# Tag synonym for crash and crashes

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

- [crash](/questions/tagged/crash): 2090 questions
- [crashes](/questions/tagged/crashes): 65 questions

So, I suggest crashes as a synonym to crash.

This is by no means an endorsement on the quality of the contents of these tags...